VB6 - Any way to get scrollbar updates while dragging thumb?
I'm using an HScrollbar with a centered thumb to send +/- position information that really wants to show immediate feedback.
In VB6, scrollbar _Change events don't occur while the thumb is being dragged, only when it's released. Is there any way to alter this behaviour? Or is there another control or means to accomplish this?

Try the Scroll event.

@BrianMStafford - That does update on every move of the thumb, which is great. But even though I can Debug.Print the .Value on each event, the UI seems to be stuck until I release the thumb, so the overall effect is the same as  the _Change event. Any other insights? I'll keep poking at it.

I don't experience the UI getting stuck... I can play a video and do a countdown timer and move the thumb without any issues.  What are you trying to do?  Perhaps you can try putting a DoEvents in the Scroll event.

@BrianMStafford - You're right that the UI isn't stuck, just my serial comms. DoEvents doesn't help. Consider this closed, I'll probably build a UC that plays better with this app. If you want some points, post an answer.
